# Use Picasso to load installed apps icon

Tags: android, picasso

- I want to get all installed apps icon:

AppDetail

```
public class AppDetail {
private CharSequence name; // Ex: com.google.youtube
private CharSequence label; // Ex: Youtube
private Drawable icon;

// Getters and setters
...
}
```

AllAppsActivity // Here I can get all apps icon

```
private void loadAllApps() {
    packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
    appDetailList = new ArrayList<AppDetail>();

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo ri : availableActivities) {
        AppDetail appDetail = new AppDetail();
        appDetail.setLabel(ri.loadLabel(packageManager));
        appDetail.setName(ri.activityInfo.packageName);
        appDetail.setIcon(ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(packageManager));
        appDetailList.add(appDetail);
    }
}
```

Now I want to use Picasso to load all icons, but Picasso requires File/String path/int resouce ID/Uri uri for load() function
What should i do? Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the type that you want to load? I thought ResolveInfo gave a resource drawable.

Comment: @EricCochran can i have resource id?

Comment: What do you mean? Yes, Picasso will load resource ids, as you stated in your original post.

Comment: now i have Drawable. how can i load these Drawable using load() function? @EricCochran

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but I thought I would share my solution for anyone else who comes across this. You can use a custom [`RequestHandler`](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/RequestHandler.java). Here is a `RequestHandler` I wrote for loading app icons using `Picasso`:

```
public class AppIconRequestHandler extends RequestHandler {

  public static final String SCHEME_PNAME = "pname";

  private final PackageManager pm;
  private final int dpi;
  private Bitmap defaultAppIcon;

  public AppIconRequestHandler(Context context) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    dpi = am.getLauncherLargeIconDensity();
    pm = context.getPackageManager();
  }

  @Override public boolean canHandleRequest(Request data) {
    return data.uri != null && TextUtils.equals(data.uri.getScheme(), SCHEME_PNAME);
  }

  @Override public Result load(Request request, int networkPolicy) throws IOException {
    try {
      return new Result(getFullResIcon(request.uri.toString().split(":")[1]), DISK);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  private Bitmap getFullResIcon(String packageName) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
    return getFullResIcon(pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0));
  }

  private Bitmap getFullResIcon(ApplicationInfo info) {
    try {
      Resources resources = pm.getResourcesForApplication(info.packageName);
      if (resources != null) {
        int iconId = info.icon;
        if (iconId != 0) {
          return getFullResIcon(resources, iconId);
        }
      }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
    }
    return getFullResDefaultActivityIcon();
  }

  private Bitmap getFullResIcon(Resources resources, int iconId) {
    final Drawable drawable;
    try {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        drawable = resources.getDrawableForDensity(iconId, dpi, null);
      } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
        drawable = resources.getDrawableForDensity(iconId, dpi);
      } else {
        drawable = resources.getDrawable(iconId);
      }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
      return getFullResDefaultActivityIcon();
    }
    return drawableToBitmap(drawable);
  }

  private Bitmap getFullResDefaultActivityIcon() {
    if (defaultAppIcon == null) {
      Drawable drawable;
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
        drawable = Resources.getSystem().getDrawableForDensity(
            android.R.mipmap.sym_def_app_icon, dpi);
      } else {
        drawable = Resources.getSystem().getDrawable(
            android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon);
      }
      defaultAppIcon = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
    }
    return defaultAppIcon;
  }

}
```

### Usage

Simply add the `RequestHandler` to your `Picasso` instance:

```
Picasso.setSingletonInstance(new Picasso.Builder(this)
    .addRequestHandler(new AppIconRequestHandler(this))
    .build());
```

Then, create a `Uri` with the scheme used in the `RequestHandler`:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(AppIconRequestHandler.SCHEME_PNAME +  ":" + "com.facebook.katana");
Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thank you so mych! I will check it